# How to change "Home" page title of wordpress site using its control panel?

Tags: wordpress

I have an Wordpress site. Want to change the title of home page.
I have only Control Panel Details.
Wordpress Credentials are not available .

Please suggest for this.

Comment: You would have to change it in the controller for the wp site, which means downloading it, changing it, re-uploading it.

Comment: Access the database via your control panel and change it directly.

Comment: In the database how to edit it

Comment: But I cannot locate the file.And what exactly does the controller means

Comment: And also if I change code in Control Panel , can the user be able to modify it again in WordPress Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how your Wordpress is setup, but you can do it by going into the database and updating the `blogname` to your new title. This will be found on the `wp_options` table.

If that doesn't work you will need to change the actual `post_title` found under `wp_posts` in your database. In this case you will need to find the correct page id and revision.